# Error, calculating covariance between two stochastic variables

Tags: stochastic-calculus

In my exercise, I'm given two independent discrete stochastic variables, with the probability function;

$$
p_{X}\left(x\right)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{4} & \text{if } x = -1 \\
\frac{1}{4} & \text{if } x = 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if } x = 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

I'm given the task to find several properties, for instance the mean ($EX = \frac{1}{4}$), and variance ($VarX=\frac{11}{16}$). I was able to do this with any issues.

Now I'm given the task of calculating, the variance; $Var(X-5Y)$, based upon the fact that independent variables have a covariance of 0, I've found this to be; $Var(X-5Y)=\frac{143}{8}$.

However when I'm trying to confirm that the covariance is 0, I get in trouble;
$$
Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - EX \cdot EY
$$
With;
$$E(XY) = \left(\frac{1}{4} \cdot -1 \cdot -1 \right)
        + \left(\frac{1}{4} \cdot 0 \cdot 0 \right)
        + \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \right)
        = \frac{3}{4}$$
I'm getting;
$$
Cov(X,Y) = \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{4}
         = \frac{11}{16}
$$
Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so $E(XY) = \left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2}\right)\cdot 1 + \left(\frac{1}{2}\frac14 + \frac14\frac12\right)\cdot (-1) = \frac{5}{16} - \frac{4}{16}$.

Comment: What would the general formula for E(XY) be? $E\left(X_{1},X_{2}\right) = \sum_{i \in I} x_{i1} x_{i2} p\left(x_{i1},x_{i2}\right)$?

Comment: $\sum P(X=x)P(Y=y)xy$ for the finite or countable case. $P(X=x)P(Y=y) = P\bigl((X=x) \land(Y=y)\bigr)$ by independence.

Comment: What would $E(XY)$ look, extended, with the finite case formula? - And how would that differ, from what I've got, clearly it should yield what you wrote, as first comment. Is my support $\{(-1,-1),(-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1)\}$?

Comment: Okay, so it seems like the support has to be $\{(-1,-1),(-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1)\}$, is it always the case, that the support for this, is the Cartesian product of the normal support?

Comment: $$\sum_{(x,y) \in \Omega_X\times\Omega_Y} P(X=x,Y=y)\cdot x\cdot y$$ That's the general definition of $E(XY)$. Here, both have the same possible outcomes, and are independent, so we obtain $$E(XY) = \sum_{y\in \Omega}\left(\sum_{x\in\Omega} P(X=x,Y=y)x\right)y = \sum_{y\in\Omega}P(Y=y)\left(\sum_{x\in\Omega}P(X=x)x\right)y = E(X)E(Y).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer: If you'd like, turn your comments into an answer, and I'll accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value of the product of two random variables is obtained by summing over all possible pairs of outcomes,

$$E(XY) = \sum_{y \in \Omega_Y}\sum_{x\in\Omega_X} P(X=x,Y=y)\cdot x\cdot y.$$

In the particular case of two independent random variables, the joint probability of a pair is the product of the probabilities of the components,

$$P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x) \cdot P(Y=y),$$

and then the sum splits

$$\begin{align}E(XY) &= \sum_{y \in \Omega_Y}\sum_{x\in\Omega_X} P(X=x)P(Y=y)\cdot x\cdot y\\
&= \sum_{x\in\Omega_X} P(X=x)\cdot x \cdot \sum_{y\in\Omega_Y} P(Y=y)\cdot y\\
&= E(X)\cdot E(Y).
\end{align}$$

For two inependent identically distributed variables with the given distribution, that is

$$\begin{align}E(XY) &= P(X=1,Y=1)\cdot1 + P(X=-1,Y=-1)\cdot 1\\
&\qquad + P(X=1,Y=-1)\cdot(-1) + P(X=-1,Y=1)\cdot (-1)\\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2}\right)\cdot 1 + \left(\frac12\frac14 + \frac14\frac12\right)\cdot (-1)\\
&= \frac{1}{16}
\end{align}$$

by the explicit summation (ignoring $0$ terms).